# why are these warnings showing up at installation time?

Tags: system-installation, 16.10

[image: watch]

the WARNINGS in the status window . why/what are they ? how can i avoid/solve them?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda the installer top left claims this is a 16.10 install. Probably a typo? :X changed it to 16.10 :+

Comment: @Rinzwind: Oh... Whoops! Sorry! I can't see the image too well on my screen and the colours make it harder to read on my screen.

Comment: I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: But this still probably would do better as a bug report on LaunchPad against Ubiquity.

Comment: Agreed probably a coding bug: the python scripts wants to remove something that is not there and errors out. Ill have a look for the script.

Comment: Here is the script: http://code.metager.de/source/xref/ubuntu/ubiquity/ubiquity/frontend/gtk_components/nmwidgets.py#DBusGMainLoop line 18 and 131 both call `   GLib.source_remove(self.timeout_id)`.

Comment: They shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

That's what these are: they are **just warnings**, *not errors* and in this case, they can be safely ignored...  **:-)**

*Disclaimer:* The above statement about ignoring warnings is not meant to make you disregard all warnings!  If you see a road sign that says:

## Warning! Bridge closed!

Please *do not* disregard that kind of warning!

#### ;-)

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If one of the answers *solved your problem*, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of its text, which means [Yes, this answer is the most useful of all](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**